# An error appeared when opening TDS Solution: 'The operation has timed out' occurred while checking for your license

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sitecore, tds

I'm trying to load a TDS solution from the Clothing Company Sample Solution provided in learning@sitecore but when I tried to load it, a few error messages appeared. First one is [Sitecore TDS license cant be verified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fflpn.png)

The second error appears when I reload the TDS project. [Project Unsupported error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXiaJ.png)

Things I have tried:

- Reinstall TDS
- Restart Visual Studio and PC
- Repair Visual Studio

The output from Visual Studio:

```
The error 'The operation has timed out' occured while checking your license.

This error occurs when Visual Studio is blocked from accessing the Sitecore license server.

Please contact developersupport@sitecore.com for more information on resolving this error.
Exception The operation has timed out (WebException):
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Hedgehog.LicensingV3.Client.ProductInfo.ProductInfo.ValidateLicense(Byte[] profileBytes)
   at Hedgehog.LicensingV3.Client.LicenseValidator.GetActivatedLicense(WorkstationProfile profile, Int32 serviceTimeoutSeconds, Boolean isMultiLicense)
   at Hedgehog.LicensingV3.Client.LicenseValidator.ActivateLicense(ILicenseInfoStore licenseInfoStore, Int32 serviceTimeoutSeconds, Boolean contactServer)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Licensing.TDSLicenseSupport.DownloadNewActivationKey(ILicenseKeyProvider licenseKeyProvider, ILicenseFailureLogger logger, Int32 serviceTimeoutSeconds, Boolean backgroundCheck)

The error 'The operation has timed out' occurred while checking your license.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this out here. Found the fix. Just have to launch visual studio without selecting any recent projects. Once the visual studio is launched, click on Continue without code and everything should be working fine.